# Dax formula to calculate except for the particular date range , I need all remaining sales

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

```
last 2 weeks uncleared sales = 

VAR Date_Range= DATESINPERIOD(Date_Table[Date], LASTDATE(Date_Table[Date]) -WEEKDAY(LASTDATE(Date_Table[Date]),2),-14,DAY)


Return

CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
    VALUES(TABLE[Sales item]),Table[sales item],UNICHAR(10)),
    Date_Ranage
    )
```

it is giving the output for last 2 weeks sales. but I need sales for all the dates except the given date_range.

ex: consider in the sales table I have sales data from 1st Jan to 22nd Jan

my VAR Date_Range expression gives 3rd Jan to 16th January.
so I need output as
**(1st jan to 2jan sales)+( 17th Jan to 22nd Jan)**
i.e remaining days sales except for the given date_range.

please help me with this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write measure this way:

```
last 2 weeks uncleared sales = 

VAR Date_Range= DATESINPERIOD(Date_Table[Date], LASTDATE(Date_Table[Date]) -WEEKDAY(LASTDATE(Date_Table[Date]),2),-14,DAY)


Return

CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
    VALUES(TABLE[Sales item]),Table[sales item],UNICHAR(10)),
    not(Date_Table[Date] in Date_Ranage)
    )
```